# Converting SQL query to LINQ is throwing not in scope error

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to convert a sql query to LINQ. Below is the SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    sst.Id,
    sst.status,
    sst.Created,
    sst.StatusChangeDate,
    sstcnt.numitemid,
    ssti.XML
FROM 
    dbo.Transaction sst
JOIN 
    (SELECT transactionid, COUNT(itemid) numitemid
     FROM dbo.TransactionItem ssti
     GROUP BY ssti.TransactionId) sstcnt ON sstcnt.TransactionId = sst.TransactionId
JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionItem ssti ON ssti.TransactionId = sst.TransactionId
WHERE
    sst.TransactionId = 'TER123'
ORDER BY 
    sst.Created DESC
```

This is what I have in LINQ:

```
var result = from sst in Context.Transactions
             join sstcnt in (
                         from ssti in Context.TransactionItems
                         group ssti by ssti.TransactionId into g
                         select new 
                                {
                                    TransactionId = g.Key, 
                                    NumItemId = g.Count() 
                                }) on sstcnt.TransactionId equals sst.TransactionId
             join ssti in Context.TransactionItems on sst.TransactionId equals ssti.TransactionId
             orderby sst.Created descending
             select new object[]
                        {
                            sst.Id,
                            sst.Status,
                            sst.Created,
                            sst.StatusChangeDate,
                            sstcnt.NumItemId,
                            ssti.XML
                        }
```

With this LINQ query, I keep getting an error on this line for both sstcnt and sst

```
on sstcnt.TransactionId equals sst.TransactionId
```

saying

> The name sstcnt is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. consider swapping the expressions on either side of equals.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Outer reference should be first in join condition `on sst.TransactionId equals sstcnt.TransactionId`. Same for another join.